# How to download multiple files from multiple url by NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, nsoperationqueue, afhttprequestoperation

I'm struggling to implement download mechanism for multiple files using AFNetworking. I want to download zip file one after another from multiple url with progression message. I tried like following code, but getting error as -

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSOperationQueue addOperation:]: operation is already enqueued on a queue'
```

Here is my code portion :

```
- (void) downloadCarContents:(NSArray *)urlArray forContent:(NSArray *)contentPaths {

    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i< urlArray.count; i++) {

        NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentDirectory getDownloadContentPath:contentPaths[i]];

        NSLog(@"Dest : %@", destinationPath);

        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:urlArray[i]
                                              parameters:nil
                                                 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                                 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                                     NSLog(@"Error : %ld", (long)error.code);
                                                 }];

        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:destinationPath append:NO];

        [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
            float percentage = (float) (totalBytesRead * 100) / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
            [self.delegate downloadProgression:percentage];
        }];

        [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `GET`, it's already added to the `operationQueue` of the `AFHTTPRequestionOperationManager`. So don't add it to a queue again.

Also, you should instantiate the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` once, before the loop, not repeated within the loop.

---

There are other problems with this code, but rather than trying to address all of these issues, I'd suggest you transition to `AFHTTPSessionManager`, which uses `NSURLSession`. The old `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` was `NSURLConnection`-based, but `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated. And, in fact, AFNetworking 3.0 has retired `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` entirely.

So, the `AFHTTPSessionManager` rendition might look like:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < urlArray.count; i++) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlArray[i]]];
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress *downloadProgress) {
        [self.delegate downloadProgression:downloadProgress.fractionCompleted * 100.0];
    } destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self.documentDirectory getDownloadContentPath:contentPaths[i]]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@" error.localizedDescription);
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how to implement progression block with NSURLSession ?

Comment: As well as can i make any dependency while downloading with this NSURLSession block ? i mean synchronizing one after another ?

Comment: Ya i'm struggling to implement NSProgress block. In your code, i got an error like "Sending 'void (^)(NSProgress *__strong)' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSProgress *__autoreleasing _Nullable * _Nullable' ". How to solve this ? And how to aggregate child NSProgress into one master NSProgress ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97804/discussion-between-nuibb-and-rob).

Comment: One question more. How can i ensure in the completionHandler block that all the contents are successfully downloaded ? I need that validation in the completionHandler block but not in the observeValueForKeyPath method by checking 1.0 fraction value completion ?

Comment: If it was successful, the `NSError` will be `nil`.

Comment: Actually i wanted to check if all the contents of different url is downloaded or not. Finally I did it by counting each finished task with the total url count in completionHandler block. By the way, thank you very much for response.

Comment: Hi Rob, from your github page, "https://github.com/robertmryan/AFHTTPSessionOperation", how can i replace AFHTTPSessionOperation by Alamofire framework for swift ?